# When using brownie I can't use external modules, pip install doesn't work brownie

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, python-imaging-library, brownie

PROBLEM: Can't import PIL module when using python 3 and brownie

When I run 'brownie run scripts/create_metadata.py --network rinkeby' I get the following error: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PIL'.

The simple solution would be to pip install pillow. The problem is that I do have it installed. Pillow shows up when I run 'pip list' in my cmd.
The error only occures when using brownie, I CAN use the PIL module when running the script regularly in python. But when I run the script using 'brownie run...' I do get the error. Below is the full output and the code.

Any tips would be greatly appreciated.

This is the code for scripts/create_metadata.py:

```
from brownie import StreamCollectible, network
from metadata.sample_metadata import metadata_template
from pathlib import Path
import requests
import json
import os
import math
import PIL

# from PIL import Image, ImageFont, ImageDraw

PINATA_BASE_URL = "https://api.pinata.cloud/"
endpoint = "pinning/pinFileToIPFS"
headers = {
    "pinata_api_key": str(os.getenv("PINATA_API_KEY")),
    "pinata_secret_api_key": str(os.getenv("PINATA_API_SECRET")),
}


def main():
    stream_collectible = StreamCollectible[-1]
    number_of_collectibles = stream_collectible.tokenCounter()
    print(f"There are {number_of_collectibles} stream collectibles")
    for token_id in range(number_of_collectibles):
        metadata_file_name = f"./metadata/{network.show_active()}/{token_id}"
        metadata = metadata_template
        if Path(metadata_file_name).exists():
            print(f"{metadata_file_name} already exists! Delete it to overwrite it")
        else:
            print(f"Creating Metadata file: {metadata_file_name}")
            metadata["name"] = f"Stream Token #{token_id}"
            metadata["description"] = ""

            img_path = f"./images/{token_id}.jpg"
            create_img(token_id)

            img_uri = None
            if os.getenv("UPLOAD_IPFS") == "true":
                img_uri = upload_pinata_IPFS(token_id)

            metadata["image"] = img_uri
            with open(metadata_file_name, "w") as file:
                json.dump(metadata, file)


def upload_pinata_IPFS(file_name):
    file_path = f"./images/{file_name}.jpg"
    with Path(file_path).open("rb") as fp:

        image_binary = fp.read()

        response = requests.post(
            str(PINATA_BASE_URL + endpoint),
            files={"file": (str(file_name), str(image_binary))},
            headers=headers,
        )
        JSON_response = response.json()

        URI = f"https://ipfs.io/ipfs/{JSON_response['IpfsHash']}?filename={file_name}.json"

        print("JSON RESPONSE")
        print(JSON_response)
        print("")
        print("URI")
        print(URI)
        return URI


def create_img(n):
    width = 17
    nList = list(str(n))
    bImage = Image.new("L", (width, width), 255)

    for i in range(len(nList)):
        xAxis = (7 - 2 * (len(nList) - 1)) + 4 * i
        nImage = Image.open(f"template/{nList[i]}.png")
        bImage.paste(nImage, (xAxis, 6))

    if not os.path.exists("./images"):
        os.makedirs("./images")
    bImage.save(f"./images/{n}.png")
    n -= 1
```

This is the full output:

```
INFO: Could not find files for the given pattern(s).
Brownie v1.17.2 - Python development framework for Ethereum

Erc721StreamtokenProject is the active project.
  File "C:\Users\user\.local\pipx\venvs\eth-brownie\lib\site-packages\brownie\_cli\run.py", line 50, in main
    return_value, frame = run(
  File "C:\Users\user\.local\pipx\venvs\eth-brownie\lib\site-packages\brownie\project\scripts.py", line 53, in run       
    module = _import_from_path(script)
  File "C:\Users\user\.local\pipx\venvs\eth-brownie\lib\site-packages\brownie\project\scripts.py", line 149, in _import_from_path
    _import_cache[import_str] = importlib.import_module(import_str)
  File "C:\Program, line line, in in
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen, line line, in in
  File "<frozen, line line, in in
  File "<frozen, line line, in in
  File "<frozen, line line, in in
  File "<frozen, line line, in in
  File "<frozen, line line, in in
  File ".\scripts\create_metadata.py", line 8, in <module>
    import PIL
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PIL'
```

Answer (score 4):

When using `brownie` installed via `pipx`, you actually install brownie in it's own virtual environment. When you run brownie, it doesn't look into your locally installed packages. You have to `inject` your modules into the brownie virtual environment, like so:

```
pipx inject eth-brownie Pillow
```

Or whatever your module is