# Use external packages in eth-brownie?

Tags: python, odbc, brownie, erc721

I am trying open a ERC721 smart contract in Brownie on VSCode and loop through the token ids and set the URI of each in each iteration. I execute the script with `brownie run scripts/parcel_asset/testpyodbc.py`. I am trying to use an ODBC driver named pyodbc to query an Access database and create a cursor to iterate. It works fine when running as just a python script but Brownie gives a error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyodbc'`. Is there a way to his odbc with Brownie?

Below is the error I get

```
\nft> brownie run scripts/parcel_asset/testpyodbc.py
Brownie v1.17.2 - Python development framework for Ethereum
File ".\scripts\parcel_asset\testpyodbc.py", line 1, in <module>
import pyodbc
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyodbc'
Terminating local RPC client...
PS C:\Users\philk\Dropbox\smartCity\nft\OrlandoMagicOrange\nft> brownie run scripts/parcel_asset/testpyodbc.py
INFO: Could not find files for the given pattern(s).
Brownie v1.17.2 - Python development framework for Ethereum

NftProject is the active project.
import pyodbc
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyodbc'
Terminating local RPC client...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this on a Discord channel:
brownie is installed to its own virtual environment, if you want other packages to work you have to "inject" them into the brownie virtualenv: [When using brownie I can't use external modules, pip install doesn't work brownie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70328304/when-using-brownie-i-cant-use-external-modules-pip-install-doesnt-work-browni)
but full disclosure, i tried this for another package i was working with to no avail.

```
pipx inject eth-brownie pyodbc
```

This fixed the problem

Answer (score 2):

If you installed brownie with `pipx`, you'll need to `inject` outside packages into your project.

So instead of

```
pip install matplotlib
```

It would be

```
pipx inject eth-brownie matplotlib
```

`pipx` installs packages into a siloed virtual environment, so you have to install into that the brownie virtual environment to use other packages.

[Related from Stack Exchange Ethereum](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/113624/possible-to-use-python-packages-inside-brownie-scripts-folder)